# Hide all divs except one

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I'd like to hide a complete div container except one div.

So, on startup just show div id "box_5" and hide the rest.
When I click button 1 show everything and when I click button 2 hide everything again.

The problem is when I hide the "wrapper" div it is hiding everything including id=box_5.

I think the problem is the div is within the wrapper div but I don't know a work-around?

```
<button id="button_1">show</botton>
<button id="button_2">hide</botton>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="box_1"></div>
<div id="box_2"></div>
<div id="box_3"></div>
<div id="box_4"></div>
<div id="box_5">always show this</div>
<div id="box_6"></div>
<div id="box_7"></div>
<div id="box_8"></div>
<div id="box_9"></div>
<div id="box_10"></div>
</div>




$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wrapper').not(":eq(#box_5)").hide();
    $('id="button_1"').click(function() {
        $('#wrapper').show();
        $('id="button_2"').click(function() {
            $('#wrapper').not(":eq(#box_5)").hide();
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change

```
$('#wrapper').not(":eq(#box_5)").hide();
```

to

```
$('#wrapper').not("#box_5").hide();
```

**Note:** Removed the `eq` selector. `eq` selector works on the index and in your case you don't need `eq` selector as you know the ID of the div.

Also please change your handler functions like below,

```
$('#button_1').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').show();
});

$('#button_2').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').not("#box_5").hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In combination with the answer of Alex its almost working.

Answer (score 2):

Add the element you want to hide to your selector, in this case the "div" elements inside the "wrapper" element. Also, fixed some of the other formatting of the selectors.

```
    $('#wrapper div').not("#box_5").hide();
    $("#button_1").click(function() {
        $('#wrapper div').show();
    });
    $("#button_2").click(function() {
        $('#wrapper div').not("#box_5").hide();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a newbie and couldn't find the problem.

It's working but now it is hiding the div inside box_5?