# Hide all elements except one, And show all elements again

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<body>
    <div id="e1">Element X1</div>
    <div id="e2">Element 2X</div>
    <div id="e3">Element X3</div>
    <a href="/" id="e3">Hide</a>
</body>
```

How can i hide the entire `body` And only show `#e2` when i click on `#hide`, But if i clicked anywhere else out of `#e2` again, the hide effect will stop and return to normal.

Comment: First of all, never never use an id twice... use  #e3button  or something for the link - you cant hide the body itself because #e3 is a child of body. What you can do is hide all divs inside body except e3 - have you got just one link and hide this link always the same id's except same / previously defined one ?

Comment: Could that might help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239331/hide-all-divs-except-one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? NB: make sure to give your hide link a unique ID.

Showing/hiding works well with jQuery `show` and `hide` methods, but since you wanted the elements to stay in their place, it is more suitable to use the `visibility` style attribute:

```js
$('#hide').click(function () {
    // hide all in body except #e2, and #e2's parents.
    $('body *').not($('#e2').parents().addBack()).css({visibility: 'hidden'});
    return false; // cancel bubbling and default hyperlink effect.
});

$('#e2').click(function () { // click on #e2
    return false; // cancel bubbling -- ignore click.
})

$(document).click(function (e) { // click on document
    $('body *').css({visibility: 'visible'}); // show all in body.
});
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="e1">Element X1</div>
<div id="e2">Element 2X</div>
<div id="e3">Element X3</div>
<a href="/" id="hide">Hide</a>
```

Be aware that these `div` elements stretch across horizontally, so a click to the right of the text "Element 2X" will still be on #e2.

Comment: Great! 9 more to go

Comment: Is it possible to keep the element in its main place? Instead of just jumping up to the head.

Comment: Sure, use `visibility` style. I will update the snippet.

Comment: there is something weird. if i replaced the div container with body the first hide will hide everything. the second hide will work as expected

Comment: It might be that `#e2` is not a direct child of `body` in your setup, and the intermediate node will get hidden. Solve this by changing the `not` to: `not($('#e2').parents().addBack())`. I updated the snippet with this, and used `body`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```js
// Get reference to the hyperlink
var hideElem = document.getElementById("e4");

// Set up click event handler for link
hideElem.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *:not(#e2)");
  
  Array.prototype.slice.call(elems).forEach(function(value){
   value.classList.add("hide");
  });
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// Set up click event handler for document
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll("body *");
  
  Array.prototype.slice.call(elems).forEach(function(value){
   value.classList.remove("hide");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.hide { display:none; }
```

```html
<div id="e1">Element X1</div>
<div id="e2">Element 2X</div>
<div id="e3">Element X3</div>
<a href="#" id="e4">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').click(function(evt){    
if(!$(evt.target).is('#e2')) {
        //If not e2 is clicked then restore the state back of page by removing a specific class 
 }
});
```

You will need help of css class .hide {display:none;} and add and remove this class when e2 is clicked and remove this class when body is clicked but not e2 as provided above